# Cross-Platform Visual Studio 2012 C# | Android

Tags: c#, android, cross-platform

Existe alguma solução fora Xamarin para desenvolver em C# aplicações Android? Acessando recursos como GPS que podemos confiar e desenvolver aplicativos comerciais?